# Simulate a rope bridge

Tags: 3d, physics, blender, rigid-bodies, softbody

I've been modeling a rope bridge, and I wanted to simulate someone walking on it, with the bridge movement and so on. For that, I've tried creating some ropes to wrap the planks and so on, and add physics to the ropes and planks, but they don't work not even by chance, either they keep shaking until they fall, or they explode and any other situation you can imagine.

I also thought about adding an armature but deformations are ugly, and the armature goes in one direction so if I try to move the opposite side of the bridge it doesn't look realistic either.

Then I've thought about constraints, but it's not feasible for the ropes unless I split them into million pieces (unless I'm missing something).
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can apply rigidbody physics on the planks and softbody physics on the rope. Adjust the stiffness of the rope until it  works fine. make sure to change the deformation of the planks from convex hull to mesh. If there is still some problem like blowing up or breaking apart, try lowering the weight of the planks and try scaling up everything.